# Hide my database password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian, password-protection, password-encryption

I just discovered that in the file

```
/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
```

My database admin password is written in clear-text with no encryption.

How can I change that? I noticed online that many people are happy with this. Although I noticed that only root can see the content of this file (its permission is 600), I still would prefer not having clear passwords.

What do you suggest?

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: I think you have to submit a mysql database password in clear text. i know what you mean. it would be nice to compare hashes

Comment: @Adsy2010 Thanks for the response. So there's no way of putting a hash there? Or even remove this? What consequences will there be if I remove this?

Comment: If no other users than you have root access to your server, why worry about leaving this as is?

Comment: the problem with having a password is it has to be matched. if its stored in a file unless theres a feature that downloads the password in hashed form. I know you can submit data in hashed form over networks but for comparison but i think you have to have the original password somewhere

Comment: Suppose you encrypt the password? where would you keep the secret? in a bash file that you use to run the server wouldn't that be the same problem?.. see http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Password for an explanation in a similar project

Comment: @VasilisLourdas I don't have a good answer to your question, and I pointed in my question that I know it's not accessible to everyone. I just see it as bad practice.

Comment: Well, my thought was that if this file becomes accessible to someone some day because of some stupid mistake from my side, then he shouldn't be easily able to just brick my system... If all my passwords are stored in mysql with hashes, and everything is submitted encrypted and is only decrypted in memory, then that's a perfect security system. Right?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I agree, but does MySQL support passwords in such configuration files other than plain text? Maybe no.

Comment: are we not just talking about phpmyadmin here? and phpmyadmin does support different authentication methods other than storing password in clear text.

Comment: @hexereisoftware I saw your answer, which is a good answer. I'm just waiting to see whether there's an alternative before I do your solution :-)

Comment: Whatever you do, PHP must ultimately have available to it sufficient information to successfully connect to MySQL.  It gets that information from files that are stored on disk.  Anyone who has access to those files can pretend to be PHP and successfully connect to MySQL.  There's nothing that you can do about that, except protect the files from being accessed by unauthorised persons: but once an unauthorised person gains access to your private files, it's already game over (MySQL or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a solution for phpmyadmin, you could change it to cookie based authentication. then create .htaccess file with db username and password where pasword is stored in encrypted password file. on first call of page you will have to login once with user and password and then a cookie is stored locally so on next call you are straight in again.

procedure also described here (but for windows):
http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-builtin-security

about creating htaccess user:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html

Comment: Honestly I'm not looking for a solution for phpmyadmin only, but for all those clear passwords in the system. However, I consider your solution a nice one for the question I asked for phpmyadmin. Thanks. :-)